# Kubuntu 14.10 create password protected archive

Tags: kubuntu, kde, archive, dolphin

I installed Kubntu 14.10 and when trying to create a new rar or 7z arhive, I see no option of adding a password to protect the file. What should I do in order to have this option from dolphin menu?

Comment: Unfortunately, `ark` (the default archive manager) doesn't support it yet, here is the bug report to track and vote for: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253694 So you have two options here: use some non-default GUI software or find/write your own Dolphin action.

Answer (score 1):

What program are you using?, I recommend using PeaZip:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/peazip/files/5.5.3/peazip_5.5.3.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb/download

On how to encrypt in PeaZip (in Windows):

This will give you a basic idea, Screenshot not working....

- Double click the Peazip shortcut on the desktop.
- You will see the following dialog box:

[image]

- Browse to the file that you want to ZIP.
- Right click on the file you want to Zip and the following options appear:

[image]

- Click on **ADD** and the following screen will appear:

[image]

- Click on the **ADVANCED** tab to get the following page:

[image]

- Check the desired Encryption Algorithm.
- Click on the **ARCHIVE TAB** again to get back to this screen:

[image]

- Click on the **LOCK** next to the **PASSWORD IS NOT SET** (right below Output).
- You’ll see the following Password entry screen pop up:

[image]

- Enter the password and enter it again to confirm password.  Leave everything else alone.
- Click **OK** to get out of the **PASSWORD** entry dialog box.
- Click **OK** and you’ll see a new ZIP file saved…usually in the same location where the file you want to ZIP is located.

Comment: Thanks DeOxyRibose Acid, I have already tried that. I just wanted to know if there's a way to do it from the context menu.